# Calling a method which refers to an object property throws a ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In the following code, the line `obj.sayhello()` means that `sayhello` executes in the context / scope of `obj`. **`str` is not defined (via `var`) in the `sayhello` method**. JS will look up the variable in the scope i.e. in the `obj` which clearly has a `str` property. Why does the script throw a `ReferenceError`?

> Uncaught `ReferenceError`: `str` is not defined at `Object.sayhello`

```js
var obj = {
    str: "hello",
    sayhello: function(){
      return str;
    }
  };

obj.sayhello();
```

Comment: `str`  is not a variable but an object property. You have to access it using `this` --`this.str` will yield the correct value.

Comment: Strongly related: [Self-references in object literals / initializers](/q/4616202/4642212) — this has the exact opposite problem, but causes a similar error. In that question, `this` is used, but not `function`; here, it’s the other way around. I’d consider those to be distinct enough that this shouldn’t be closed as a duplicate. Also related: [var vs this in Javascript object](/q/4946625/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're in the obj scope, you should return `this.str`.

`str` by itself is not a variable in its plain definition, its a property of an object. Hence, you cannot simply access `str` but you have to access `something.str`. If outside the object, this would be `obj.str`, if inside the object- `this.str`.

Answer (score 0):

For reference to same object you need to use a `this`, `return str;` => `return this.str;`

```
var obj = {
    str: 'hello',
    sayhello: function (){ return this.str; } // <==
}

obj.sayhello()
```